# Rails cannot find my Postgres server on Mac OS X / PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am following a rails tutorial and am trying to do a simple migration but my rails app is having trouble finding my Postgres server (I'm using mac OS X).

When I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` on my rails app, I get the following error

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I type `sudo lsof -i tcp:5432` I get the output

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres  73 postgres    4u  IPv6 0xd0338068e4dc128d      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres  73 postgres    5u  IPv4 0xd0338068e4852e55      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

So Postgres is clearly running on port 5432.

What could be the solution?

Comment: Are you able to connect to postgres via `psql`?

Comment: Yes psql runs fine

Comment: Did you try just to reinstall gem? I mean remove it completely and install again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved:**

add

```
host: localhost
```

to the database.yml file